# How to write raw HTML entities in md files?

Tags: html, github, markdown, html-entities, html-encode

How to write `&#169;` in README.md file in GitHub?

So it will display `&#169;`, not ©.

Comment: Like this: `&amp;#169;`

Comment: Try using this https://stackedit.io/. This will help you to create a well formatted .MD file and you can commit to any git repo too. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the HTML entity for `&` at the start: `&amp;`

This gives you `&amp;#169;`